# Modify response file in express.js static server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Sorry, didn't know how to word the title.

I want to setup `express.static` middleware, but I want to be able to do `/static/image.png?blur=10` and node.js will send the regular image, applied with a blur effect. I am able to apply the blur effect, and the static server works by itself, but I don't know where to check if the file is a png/jpg and check the query parameters in order to apply the possible blur.

Thanks!

Comment: Then it's not static, is it?

Comment: Well, a static file would be stored, but there would just be a custom filter applied afterwords. Would I have to make something similar to the middleware, but with my custom code inside?

Comment: Static but dynamic? Come on, you know the answer by yourself already..